# How to remove axes and numbers from Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have the following picture, and I want to remove everything besides the dots and the triangle, which means the numbers on the horizontal and vertical axes and the small vertical lines, how can I do it?

Here is the picture:

[image: Triangle]

And here is my code:

```
x0 = np.average(triangleEdges,axis=0,weights=np.array([0.2,0.1,0.7]))[0]
y0 = np.average(triangleEdges,axis=0,weights=np.array([0.2,0.1,0.7]))[1]

x1 = np.average(triangleEdges,axis=0,weights=np.array([0.5,0.1,0.7]))[0]
y1 = np.average(triangleEdges,axis=0,weights=np.array([0.5,0.1,0.7]))[1]


trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[x0],
    y=[y0],
    marker = dict(
        size = 15,
        color = 'rgba(25, 181, 254, 1)',
        line = dict(
            width = 1,
            color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        )
    )
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[x1],
    y=[y1],
    marker = dict(
        size = 15,
        color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
        line = dict(
            width = 1,
            color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
        )
    )
)


data = [trace0,trace1]
layout = {

'xaxis': { 

    'range': [0.2, 1],
    'zeroline': False,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'range': [0, 1],
        'showgrid': False,
    },
    'shapes': [
       
       
        # filled Triangle
        {
            'type': 'path',
            'path': ' M 0.2 0 L 1 0 L 0.6 1 Z',
            'fillcolor': 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)',
            'line': {
                'color': 'rgb(44, 160, 101)',
            },
        },
       
    ]
}
fig = {
    'data': data,
    'layout': layout,
}

py.iplot(fig, filename='shapes-path')
```

Answer (score 31):

To turn off the axes:

```
'xaxis': {
    'range': [0.2, 1],
    'showgrid': False, # thin lines in the background
    'zeroline': False, # thick line at x=0
    'visible': False,  # numbers below
}, # the same for yaxis
```

also if you want to remove the legend:

```
layout = {
    'showlegend': False,
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the numbers and replace them with categories on yaxis?

Answer (score 25):

To turn off axes in newer versions:

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only a single `update_layout` call:

```
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis=dict(visible=False),
    yaxis=dict(visible=False),
)
```